# Azure Mobile App and Authentication

Tags: c#, azure, authentication, xamarin, azure-mobile-services

I have a Mobile App I am writing, at present it is simply the To Do Item list quick start application with custom Authentication added.  I have the associated Xamarin Forms app.

From the App I am able to login using the LoginAsync method, my website returns a token and shows the username I am logging in as, but subsequent calls suggest I am not authorised.

After a bit of debugging, I can see that the request arrives at the web server with the X-ZUMO-AUTH header and the token in the value, but I can see that the User does not seem to be populated and the call to the GetAllTodoItems method is returned as 401:Unauthorized.

In the startup code for the website, the ConfigureMobileApp contains the following:

```
    app.UseWebApi(config);

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(settings.HostName))
    {
        // This middleware is intended to be used locally for debugging. By default, HostName will
        // only have a value when running in an App Service application.
        app.UseAppServiceAuthentication(new AppServiceAuthenticationOptions
        {
            SigningKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SigningKey"],
            ValidAudiences = new[] { ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ValidAudience"] },
            ValidIssuers = new[] { ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ValidIssuer"] },
            TokenHandler = config.GetAppServiceTokenHandler()
        });
    }
```

I have an account controller class:

```
[Route(".auth/login/custom")]
public class AccountController : ApiController
{
    private static string URL = "https://myapidev.azurewebsites.net/";
    private static string KEY = "FC31EB8CAAAAAA9D74EEE3613A7A08CA65CB1ACAA8CEFF82A5B5E915625B31D";

    public AccountController()
    {

    }
    [HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody] LoginUser assertion)
    {
        if (isValidAssertion(assertion))
        {
            JwtSecurityToken token = AppServiceLoginHandler.CreateToken(new Claim[] { new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, assertion.username) },
                ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SigningKey"],
                ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ValidAudience"],
                ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ValidIssuer"],
                TimeSpan.FromHours(24));

            return Ok(new LoginResult()
            {
                authenticationToken = token.RawData,
                user = new LoginResultUser() { userId = assertion.username }
            });
        }
        else // user assertion was not valid
        {
            return ResponseMessage(Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, "Invalid Request"));
        }
    }

    private bool isValidAssertion(LoginUser assertion)
    {
        return assertion != null;
    }
}
```

The TodoItemController contains the following:

```
[Authorize]
[MobileAppController]
public class TodoItemController : TableController<TodoItem>
{
    protected override void Initialize(HttpControllerContext controllerContext)
    {
        base.Initialize(controllerContext);
        EducaterAPIDevContext context = new EducaterAPIDevContext();
        DomainManager = new EntityDomainManager<TodoItem>(context, Request);

        //// Get the SID of the current user.
        //var claimsPrincipal = this.User as ClaimsPrincipal;
        //string sid = claimsPrincipal.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
    }

    // GET tables/TodoItem
    public IQueryable<TodoItem> GetAllTodoItems()
    {
        return Query();
    }
    ...
    ...
}
```

On calling the query method from the Xamarin App, it returns with 401 even though the X-ZUMO-AUTH is in the headers and contains the correct token issued by the login method.

Have I missed something or has anyone come across this issue before - any help would be appreciated?

Comment: Never used Azure for mobile but here is 2 articles which may point what is wrong. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/announcing-app-service-authentication-authorization/ and https://www.newventuresoftware.com/blog/custom-authentication-with-azure-mobile-apps

Answer (score 0):

Have you turned on Authentication/Authorization in your App Service?  Without it, the token will never be decoded.

This is the most common issue.

Comment: And check out the custom auth section of my book - http://aka.ms/zumobook

Comment: I have the "Authentication / Authorization" turned on in Azure with the Action set to Allow Request.  None of the services are configured as I am only looking to use the custom option at present.
Does the Azure setting have an influence on local debug?

Comment: The local debug settings are on active on local debug and you have to set the ValidAudience / ValidIssuer / SigningKey values in the Web.config when running locally.  When running within Azure, these are handled for you by the Authn/Authz feature (which is why you need it turned on).  Try turning on diagnostic logging at the verbose level, watch the Log Stream and re-submit - see if there are any issues there.

Comment: I have found that the app will work against Azure - I had an issue with configuration which I spotted via the logs thanks, but when run against a local debug version and add the Azure app as the AlternateLoginHost then the authentication is not working locally.  The trace logs do not show any errors processing the header or any attempt to look at the header.  I have looked at several of the local debugging guides and all appears to be correct so I assume I am still missing something

Comment: @AdrianHall  I'm having the same issue as Mike C was having.  The auth works when on Azure, but doesn't when on my local.  I've checked the SigningKey,ValidAudience & ValidIssuers value in the startup and web.config at least 5 times.  I've also verified that it  UseAppServiceAuthentication is being hit on startup.  I've turned on verbose tracing at the server, but i'm not seeing any activity.  The request seems to be rejected before displaying any information at the server.  The [authorize] attribute is rejecting the request before any token information is being displayed.  Any ideas?  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After digging I found the issue, initially there was a configuration issue - the above comments helped thanks.  The Audiences and Issuers must match your azure site including including the trailing slash.

The issue once the configuration had been corrected was that the token which is passed correctly from my App did not get processed at the server side so all Authorized areas where out-of-bounds.  This was because of the order of calls in the ConfigureMobileApp method.  I was calling the **app.UseWebApi** method before the **app.UseAppServiceAuthentication** method, changing the order suddenly had the token being tested again.

The dummy site I have working now has the following:

```
    public static void ConfigureMobileApp(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();

        //For more information on Web API tracing, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=620686 
        SystemDiagnosticsTraceWriter traceWriter = config.EnableSystemDiagnosticsTracing();

        new MobileAppConfiguration()
            .UseDefaultConfiguration()
            .MapApiControllers()
            .ApplyTo(config);

        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        // Use Entity Framework Code First to create database tables based on your DbContext
        //Database.SetInitializer(new EducaterAPIDevInitializer());

        // To prevent Entity Framework from modifying your database schema, use a null database initializer
        // Database.SetInitializer<EducaterAPIDevContext>(null);

        MobileAppSettingsDictionary settings = config.GetMobileAppSettingsProvider().GetMobileAppSettings();
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(settings.HostName))
        {
            var options = new AppServiceAuthenticationOptions
            {
                SigningKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SigningKey"],
                ValidAudiences = new[] { ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ValidAudience"] },
                ValidIssuers = new[] { ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ValidIssuer"] },
                TokenHandler = config.GetAppServiceTokenHandler()
            };
            app.UseAppServiceAuthentication(options);
        }
        app.UseWebApi(config);
    }
```

Comment: You should definitely check out Adrian's book.  It is absolutely great.  Heads off almost all problems before you get to them and the writing style is excellent.  Highly recommended.